# How Elasticsearch generate the unique _id value?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm asking simply out of my favor to the look of its result string and am wondering if the algorithm has some kind of library so that I can use in my own code (C#).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the answer to [this question in the Elasticsearch discuss](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-algorithm-is-elasticsearch-create-document-id-based-on-could-somebody-answer-me-plz/166317).

You can find the source code to the method linked there [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/TimeBasedUUIDGenerator.java#L49).

Elasticsearch is written in Java, so you won't be able to import this method into your c# project.

If you don't need  the specific optimizations that the Elasticsearch-Team implemented in this method, you can use the [build in UUID generator of .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-5.0). Or you can look for other [UUID libraries on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=uuid).

If you just like the format of the Elasticsearch IDs you can also base64 encode your GUIDs/UUIDs to get similar looking IDs:

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
var base64GUID =  System.Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Basically I need a UUID function, and just like the generated result of ES:-). I'll try to copycat the Java implementation in C#.

Comment: If there's any alternative UUID generator, please kindly name a few for me to research. thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer with links to possible alternatives.

Comment: Nah, I don't want the GUID format. I like the ES output format. That's the origin of this post. lol. It's shorter in length, while still remaining uniqueness. Ain't that cool?

Comment: They only look different because they are using base64 encoding instead of hex. You can achieve the same look by using base64 encoding for your IDs. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Interesting. The code you provide is different from what I'd think. I used the encoding to first `GetBytes` then `ToBase64String` and the result differ a lot. Don't know why. However, using your code, the result UUID string will always end up with two equal operators `==`.

Comment: This is padding added to the end of the string because the GUID has 16 bytes and base64 encoding takes 3 bytes and encodes them as 4 characters. The Elasticsearch code is using a method that doesn't use padding:
Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(uuidBytes);

Comment: Finally end up with this code `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray())`, whic looks quite similar to the _id generated by ES. The only difference is that ES generates the value with 20 characters, while C# code generates 22 characters.